# Eclipse Cucumber plugins

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

What is the most most efficient way to work with Cucumber in Eclipse? I tried these plugins:

- [Natural](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/natural) - allows Ctrl+Click navigation to step methods
- [Cucumber-Eclipse](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse) - allows creation of step definitions and running Cucumber features

Should I have both plugins and use one for writing new steps and the other one for exploring old?

Answer (score 3):

We are using [QAF BDD Editors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors). It provides QAF BDD and Gherkin Editors with

- syntax highlighting
- content assist - auto completion
- feature outline
- syntax validation
- open step declaration (ctrl+click or F3).

It works fine with Cucumber Gherkin as well as QAF BDD and Gherkin.

Comment: Strangely I cannot install it by dragging the button. This plugin is also not found with Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Find. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors/help also does not work since there is no such plugin.

Comment: @vytenis Now you should take a look into https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with Natural, which allows allows Ctrl+Click navigation to step methods. To create step definition, you could simply use a chrome plugin - **Tidy Gherkin**